# T-SQL QUERY FILTERING RESULTING IN INFINITE EXECUTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Just sharing my experience, and maybe can i get some clarifications/confirmations.

I'am executing a certain script which will return Customer Information.
This script has at least 5 to 10 joined tables(with pivots-joined tables), and most likely to return at least 100k records.

The thing is, when i tried to add filter on my WHERE clause - "STATUS != 'CLOSED'", my query runs forever.
When i change it to "STATUS != 'CLOSE'", my query runs at least 2 minutes.

Also, please be informed that "CLOSED" is not existing.

Is this some kind of bug? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

most likely because it needs to scan all records and output them,where in CLOSE example it probably excludes a lot of records.
Without sharing a query, execution plans it is hard to comment here.
Also a side note having 10 table joins, pivots and other stuff lumped in one query is usually not recommended.